# I have Thomson 585v7 ... what flags mean in hostmgr list output?

Tags: command-line, router

When using `hostmgr list` there are "Flags" parameters, and I need someone to describe it to me!

Example output:

```
MAC-address       IP-address      Flags   Type             Intf            Hw Intf    Hostname            
-----------       ----------      -----   ----             ----            -------    --------            
00:04:1f:7a:c2:46 192.168.1.65    D       Generic Device   -               -          Unknown-00-04-1f-7a-c2-46
00:12:17:db:e1:74 192.168.1.65    C       Gaming Console   LocalNetwork    wlif1      Gamingadaptor       
00:14:51:81:54:a2 192.168.1.64    D       Laptop Computer  LocalNetwork    wlif1      Guffsibook          
00:14:7f:a2:de:05 192.168.1.254   T       SpeedTouch       -               -          BThomehub           
00:30:65:1b:f3:2c 192.168.1.66    CDL     Generic Device   LocalNetwork    wlif1      Bobbinspowerbookg4
```

What does each flag mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it :)
C: Connected
D: Dhcp Leased
L: Lock the lease for a specific device

Comment: Searching for this exact question, I found this useful but it would be nice if you had also quoted your source so the complete list might be obtained (such as `T`).

Comment: Also searching for this question. My guess about `T` would be that it shows whether modem device is connected. I am guessing this based on the expanded output of the command. Some Thomson router commands have expanded output e.g; `hostmgr list expand=enabled`